How to increase canvas size, and PowerBi embed report height using React TypeScript
I want to increase the height of PowerBi Embedded report with responsiveness, but I can't see changes whenever I apply changes to the styling:
enter image description here
I just want to increase the height a little bit so that it wont look that small in height, but also making its responsiveness, one problem that I am also facing is that whenever I adjust the screen width the report reloads and zooms out the report making it hard to see on load. here is my current code:

<Grid item xs={10} sm={10} md={10} lg={10} xl={10} ref={containerRef} style={{ height: '500px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <PowerBIEmbed
                embedConfig = {{
                    type: 'report',
                    id: reportId,
                    embedUrl: embedUrl,
                    groupId: groupId,
                    datasetIds: datasetID,
                    permissions: models.Permissions.Read,
                    accessToken: embeddedToken,
                    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                    settings: {
                        layoutType: 0,
                        zoomLevel: .75,
                        filterPaneEnabled: true,
                        navContentPaneEnabled: true, 
                        bars: {
                            actionBar: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            statusBar: {
                                visible: false
                            }
                        },
                        panes: {
                            filters: {
                                expanded: false,
                                visible: false
                                
                            },
                            pageNavigation: { 
                                visible: true,
                                position: 1 
                            },
                            bookmarks: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            fields: {
                                expanded: false
                            },
                            selection: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            syncSlicers: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            visualizations: {
                                expanded: false
                            }
                        },
                        background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
                    },
                    
                    filters: [basicFilter],
                    eventHooks: {

                    },
                   
                }}
                eventHandlers = {
                    new Map([
                        ['loaded', function () {
                            console.log('[+] Report loaded');
                            const containerHeight = containerRef.current?.offsetHeight;
                            console.log('Container height:', containerHeight);
                  
                            
                            if (report) {
                                
                                const currentZoom = report.getZoom();
                                console.log('Current zoom level:', currentZoom);

                                
                                const appliedFilters = report.getFilters();
                                console.log('Applied filters:', appliedFilters);
                            }
                          }],
                          ['rendered', function () {
                            console.log('Report rendered');
                            const reportHeight = report?.element.offsetHeight;
                            console.log('Report height:', reportHeight);
                            
                          }],
                        ['error', async function (event: service.ICustomEvent<any> | undefined): Promise<void> {
                            console.log(event?.detail);
                            
                        }],
                        ['visualClicked', () => console.log('visual clicked')],
                        ['pageChanged', (event: service.ICustomEvent<any> | undefined): void => console.log(event)]
                    ])
                }
                getEmbeddedComponent = { (embeddedReport: Embed) => {
                    
                    console.log(`Embedded object of type "${embeddedReport.embedtype}" received`);
                    
                    const iframe = embeddedReport?.element?.querySelector('iframe');
                    if (iframe) {
                        
                        iframe.style.height = iframeHeight.toString();
                        iframe.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                    }
                    console.log(embeddedReport.element);
                    setReport(embeddedReport as Report);
                    console.log("Version: 63")
                    
                }}
                
            />
        </Grid>



LMK if the problem still exist.

Pass the prop cssClassName to PowerBIEmbed. Refer to this sample demo app code on how to pass this prop.
Once you pass this prop, the className will be added to the div of the iframe where it gets added. Apply styling to your div and now it will reflect to the PowerBI Embedded Report. Refer to this code in sample demo app code where styling was applied.

Hey, Thanks for replying, will try this and will let you know once it got resolved
